# Fatal error: Call to a member function safesql() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

Залил движок на хостинг,захожу на сайт, а там белая рабочая область и всего одна строка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function safesql() on a non-object in /home/u223201373/public_html/system/modules/login.php on line 10

Ругается на вот такую строчку:

```
$_IP = $db->safesql($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: Не знаем и знать не можем, что у вас в движке. Но в переменной $db должен был оказаться объект для работы с БД, которого там не оказалось.

Comment: Дополню Etki. Скорее всего вы **а)** не залили БД **б)**  не настроили подключение к БД в конфиге **в)** если и настроили то неправильно **г)** что-то еще